# To which doctrine2 script do I point Netbeans if my webserver is remote? - using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, netbeans-7

Can anybody give me a hint?

My environment is:

- I am developing on a Windows 7 machine running Netbeans IDE 7.2
- I am using a (headless) Ubuntu 12.04 as web- and databaseserver on a home network
- I have just started using PHP / Symfony2 and am struggling to complete the setup of my environment
- I have installed a PHP engine on my Windows machine in order to get a PHP interpreter but don't want to maintain a webserver on this machine too.

Now I want to tell Netbeans where to look for a Doctrine2 script to exploit the Doctrine IDE support in Netbeans. But as Doctrine is not installed on my development machine, it cannot find any Doctrine2 script.

What are my options?

Comment: I am not sure that would solve it as the main problem seems to be the way the Symfony2 Standard distribution handles Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

This is only kind of a hint, since I'm only used to working with a virtual linux installation:

- Provide a shared folder on your Windows machine
- Mount that shared folder on your Ubuntu machine
- Use that shared folder as apache document root for example

Now you can work with the files on your local machine, and your server is able to pull those files for serverside stuff.

Might also work vice versa, sharing your webroot, or whatever directory doctrine is in, as a shared folder, so that Netbeans on your Windows machine can pull it via network.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve anything as I am simply missing the file. I installed Doctrine via Symfony2 standard distribution. Apparently the Doctrine Console is not part of this distribution, e.g. no vendor/bin/doctrine. However it is possible to run Doctrine commands via Symfony run command - the doctrine commands show up in the collection of commands you can run there. So ... my only problem is where Netbeans IDE should look to support Doctrine while I am typing.

Comment: So you can run doctrine commands without having vendor/bin/doctrine available? From what I read, you'd have to install doctrine, e.g. via composer, to have it available.

Comment: Yes, Doctrine is an integrated bundle in Symfony2 and my (new, homemade) bundle can use it and read the database. So everything works OK. But I know that Netbeans could help me more (autocompletion) when I am typing, if it had access to the file.